# Error when Publishing Web App using FTP to IIS 10 server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, ftp, web-publishing

I have an Up and Running web Application that I would like to publish using FTP to a IIS 10 Server.

By doing a simple publish process, I'm getting this error:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<PublishAsync>b__2()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__108.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.<---

===================
```

I would like to get find out about this error and fix it. Actually my build is successful and with No Error. But Why I cant Publish any simple website to IIS 10 server using FTP?

Should I enable the FTP under the IIS server? but How if so?

Please anyone ideas and straight forwards answers is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Open up the windows search and type: IIS you will see the configurator for IIS here you goto your domain or IP and go to the FTP enable this, If not open port 21 in your firewall for incoming connections

Comment: @mauricebruijn Thanks for your answer, But I can be able to See and configure the FTP locally. But in my case, ther is a stand alone IIS server with windows server 2012 Install. And I cant see the FTP option anywhere when I open the IIS server.

Comment: maybe this helps you out: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server

Comment: @mauricebruijn You Link is very nice. And I wish I could use it. unfortunately, The Network manager just told me that there is no way to enable the FTP on the server because there is an IIS server running with many sites already. So I have to figure something else, like any other way I could. So that is why I try to tell you that if there is a way for me to publish my website on the IIS server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today, I was having the same problem and just came over this question and noticed that it was not answered so I thought to write about how I solved this error.

So, there could be more solutions but in my case I wasn't passing a correct path for the site, What I was passing was a complete path mentioned on the server which caused me an error mentioned above, *In order to solve it,* what I did was modified the complete path of the site with only the folder name where I was willing to publish the website.

So, for example, What I was trying to pass was this path *h:\root\xx\xxxx\www\site1* in `site path` field of the publish wizard of visual studio. Which I then replaced with only the directory name of the ftp account,
I changed the full path of the site to just `site1` and it started publishing the website.

Comment: @Codelt; this is was the actual problem and was solved using the simular approach! And that is the reason why I have appointed your answer to be the right one! great thanks again

Comment: Glad to share my experience, hope it will help others in future :)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else ran into a similar problem, but when you publish into an already existing folder profile:

In my case, running Visual Studio as administrator resolved the error and it published just fine!

Comment: @mmeumann, I have tried that too but did not work for me. I'm sure for someone else would probably work. Thank you